# Destructure array of objects, default value

Tags: javascript, destructuring

I would like to set the default value of an object property if the value is `undefined`.

When destructing from the `tags` array, the `name` property, I would like to rename the property to `colour`, and set the default value if its undefined.

How can I do that?

I currently get **name not defined** with the code below:

```
const {
  description,
  categories,
  id,
  title,
>>  tags: [{ name: colour= 'none' }], <<
  organizer: [{ organizer: organiser }],
  venue: { venue }
} = event;
```

This gives me `colour is undefined`

```
            const {
                description,
                categories,
                id,
                title,
                tags: [{name:colour = "none"}={name:"none"}]=[{name:"none"}],
                organizer: [{ organizer: organiser }],
                venue: { venue }
            } = event;
```

Sample data:

```
const sample = {"tags":[{"name":"red","slug":"red","term_group":0,"term_taxonomy_id":125,
"taxonomy":"post_tag","description":"","parent":0,"count":1,"filter":"raw","id":125,"urls"}]}

or empty const sample = {"tags":[]}
```

Comment: can you provide a sample data structure of event where tags is both defined and not defined. thankx

Answer (score 1):

Does this help?

```
var {x,y,z,t:[{name:colour = "none"}]=[{name:"none"}]} = {x:3,y:2,z:1,t:[{name:"gray"}]};
console.log(colour);//"gray"
```

If t does not exist in the object:

```
var {x,y,z,t:[{name:colour = "none"}]=[{name:"none"}]} = {x:3,y:2,z:1};
console.log(colour);//"none"
```

PS: It seems to be in your object "t" might be defined as an empty array, in that case:

```
 var {x,y,z,t:[{name:colour = "none"}={name:"none"}]=[{name:"none"}]} = {x:3,y:2,z:1,t:[]};
console.log(colour);//"none"
```

PS2: Here is proof of concept from the sample data you provided:

```
var {x,y,z,tags:[{name:colour = "none"}={name:"none"}]=[{name:"none"}]} = {x:3,y:2,z:1,"tags":[{"name":"red","slug":"red","term_group":0,"term_taxonomy_id":125,
"taxonomy":"post_tag","description":"","parent":0,"count":1,"filter":"raw","id":125,"urls":"some"}]};
console.log(colour);//"red"
```

Although I should say the original example you post and the sample data you provide do not have identical structure. In your original post other properties like description etc are outside the tags key whereas in the sample you provide everything is inside the tags array.

Comment: Still gives me colour is undefined

Comment: Does the snippet work or it gives undefined on your object? Could you post a sample object?

Comment: It seems to me your tag keys lacks the entire object inside. So see my PS.

Comment: hmm, still get colour undefined, think I need a break

Comment: As you can see in PS2 I cannot reproduce the behavior you get, even with the object you provided. You are not using some sort of polyfill are you?